# getting break point by deleting the space of the heap

Tags: c++

In this code user enter the matrix arrays with any column number and i check the matrix columns of the rows that user enter.if the columns of the row doesn't match together i want to delete the space that i get it from the heap space before.when i wanna delete the space of the (int **row)in the heap, if number of the columns be over 5,the program get me a break point.i wanna know why?

`enter code here`

```
Input(mtx->matrix, &(mtx->matrixDim).column, callinpnum++);/*calling the function Input*/

void Input(int** row, int* columnmat, int callinpnum)
{
char ch = 0;
int colkeep = 0;
int counter1 = 1;
int counter2 = 0;
int counter3 = 0;
static int* guard = nullptr;/*it check the column matching*/
int colcompute = 0;
int* tmp = nullptr;
int* dynamic = nullptr;

int* tmp1 =new int [callinpnum + 1];/*getting new space for the guard to keep the numbers of new rows columns.*/
if(guard)
{
    for(int i = 0;i < (callinpnum);i++)
    {
        tmp1[i] = guard[i];
    }
    delete guard;
    guard = nullptr;
}
guard = tmp1;/*guard save the number number of the columns of each row.*/

cout << "Enter the elements of the row " << callinpnum + 1 << endl;
while (ch != ';')
{
    counter2++;
    if (counter2 % 5 == 1)/*getting new space for the user to enter the new arrays(columns).*/
    {
        tmp = new int[counter1 * 5];
        if (dynamic)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < (counter1 - 1) * 5; i++)
            {
                tmp[i] = dynamic[i];
            }
            delete dynamic;
            dynamic = nullptr;
        }
        counter1++;
        dynamic = tmp;
        row[callinpnum] = (dynamic);
    }
    //colkeep = (counter2 - 1);

    for (; colkeep < counter1 * 5 && ch != ';'; colkeep++)
    {
        row[callinpnum][colkeep] = 0;
        cin >> ch;
        if (ch == ',' || ch == ';')
        {
            colcompute++;
        }
        while (ch != ',' && ch != ';')
        {
            row[callinpnum][colkeep] = (row[callinpnum][colkeep] * 10) + (ch - 48);
            cin >> ch;
            if (ch == ',' || ch == ';')
            {
                colcompute++;
            }
        }
    }
    counter2 = colkeep;
}
guard[callinpnum] = colcompute;
if(callinpnum > 0)/*checking.*/
{
    for(int i = 0;i < callinpnum;i++)
    {
        if(guard[i] != guard[i+1])
        {
            cout<<"Your matrix columns doesn't match together\n";
            (int i = 0; i <= callinpnum; i++)
            {
                delete row[i];/*if the column number be over 5 break from the program.*/
                row[i] = nullptr;
            }

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by running a debug-build in a debugger, to pinpoint the location of the crash. Then when the crash happens, look at values of involved variables, for example if any pointer is `NULL`. If you still can't figure it out, update your question to show only the relevant code, as well as pointing out on which line the crash happens and the values of the involved variables. Also please edit your question to show how you *call* this function.

Comment: Actually I'm wrong in my previous comment... Start by stop using pointers! Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead.

Comment: i have been commented the line of the crash.please give me a solution to use the pointers.i need it.

Comment: I assume that it's in a `for` loop? Then the condition `i <= callinpnum` is *very* suspect.

Comment: the term (i<=callinpnum) is for the deleting the columns of the row[callinpnum] that when i debug it it has the address.also it gets the break point when the column numbers was over 5 and in less column it doesn't get break point.

Comment: So `callinpnum` is the highest *index* and not the size? You use it as a size in other loops (where you have conditions like `i < callinpnum`).

Comment: callinpnum is the short of call Input number and show the number of the calling function "Input".so in the loop that the condition is the (i < callinpnum) i have the new place in heap memory by the size of (callinpnum) so i want to copy the "callinpnum - 1" number of the arrays that it saved in the guard in the last calling function "Input".and in the loop that the condition is the (i<=callinpnum) i want to delete all of the "callinpnum" row that the user completed them.

Comment: And `callinpnum` *is* a valid index in `row`? How do you create `mtx->matrix`? If you do e.g. `mtx->matrix = new int*[callinpnum]` then the index is definitely out of bounds.

Comment: yes it is valid.before calling the function of Input i check the bound and then send the callinpnum.(mtx->matrix) creation is in the other function and i check the bound with the proper condition before calling function "Input".also i wrote that the crash happened when the columns numbers in the row[i] was been over than 5 or 6.and also when i debug it by the visual studio i watched that the row[i] that it has columns over 6 had address in heap but i don't know why the crash happens?i myself think that the problem is relevant to where i paired the (row[callinpnum] = dynamic)!!!

Comment: Thy crash happens when you delete the "rows", but the problem isn't there. Instead it *can* be when you initialize `row` (or rather `mtx->matrix`), *or* when you write to `rov[x]` (for an `x` around `4` or `5`) and you write out of bounds of the data allocated for `row[i]`. The crash when you `delete` is just a symptom of a problem somewhere else, so you need to step through your code when you allocate and where you write.